# Footer has margin bottom on small devices

Tags: html, css

My website has a margin-bottom on small devices coming from ("I have no clue where").It squeezes the text down there and makes a gap between html itself and the body. I was looking everywhere, but it doesn't change. I appeal to you and to your wisdom and experience. Help me to find the issue, please. This is my website which is online now: [enter link description here](http://web-artist.co.uk)

P.S. I don't know if there is needed my code if you can inspect my webpage directly. Sorry if I am wrong.

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link to the site 
that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once 
the problem is solved or if the site you're linking to is inaccessible. Posting a 
[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (MCVE)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that 
demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see 
[Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) 
Thanks!

Comment: I get it,sorry for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you have a set height on your `.footerstyle`. I'd recommend removing the height property and adding 15px of padding to the bottom.

I can see you are using bootstrap and use the following classes on your columns:

`col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4`

You could technically remove "col-md-4" and "col-sm-4" in order to get the same exact output. However, I would recommend changing up your footer so the columns stack for mobile devices with the following classes:

`col-sm-4 col-xs-12`

You will also want to make sure to add in some spacing between the columns once they begin to stack

Comment: Great job dude! How could I forget about that. Thx, you rock!!